# Rails merge multiple object into one array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I am creating API. Using ActiveRecords. Problem I am getting 
Multiple array object of country, all I want one array containing all location

**Current Output**

```
{
  "id": "180a096",
  "country": [
      {
          "location": "US"
      },
      {
          "location": "CH"
      }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "id": "180a096",
  "country": [
      {"location":["US","CH"]}
  ]
}
```

**Code**

```
  def as_json(options={})
   super(:only => [:id ],:include => { :country => { :only => :location } })
  end
```

Can anyone help me to restructured the object as in expected output.

Comment: Can you use a custom method to do so? For example (even if does not give the exact expected output): `current_hash[:country].map! {  |country| country[:location] }` gives `# => {:id=>"180a096", :country=>["US", "CH"]}`

Answer (score 0):

If your hash is called `hash` you can do:

`hash[:country].map {|h| h[:location]}`

If you have to access attributes on associated models you can do:

`countries.pluck(:location)`

Unrelated to the question, but when I have to manage country info in my app I tend to use the `countries` gem. https://github.com/hexorx/countries

It has all kinds of useful helper methods, and it prevents you from having to maintain standardized country information.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map all the location and assign it to hash[:country]

```
 2.4.0 :044 > hash[:country].map! { |c| c[:location] }
 => ["US", "CH"] 
 2.4.0 :045 > hash
 => {:id=>"180a096", :country=>["US", "CH"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in **my comment**, you can do in one line like

```
actual_hash[:country].map! { |country| country[:location]}
actual_hash # => {:id=>"180a096", :country=>["US", "CH"]}
```

The output is clean but not as expected.

Or, a bit more lines to get the exact output:

```
location_array = [{location: []}]
actual_hash[:country].each { |country| location_array[0][:location] << country[:location]}
actual_hash[:country] = location_array
actual_hash # => {:id=>"180a096", :country=>[{:location=>["US", "CH"]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rearrange_json(input)
  input_hash = JSON.parse(input)
  output_hash = input_hash.clone
  output_hash[:country] = {location: []}
  input_hash[:country].map {|l| output_hash[:country][:location] << l[:location] }
  output_hash.as_json
end
```

With this method, you can convert your json to a hash, then rearrange its content they way you want by adding the country codes as values for the `[:country][:location]` key of the output hash, and end up with some properly formatted json. It's not a one-liner, and probably not the most elegant way to do it, but it should work.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.